# Restore packages

Tags: visual-studio-2013, teamcity

A svn commit failed within TeamCity (Enterprise 9.1.7 (build 37573)).
The VS 2013 project can be rebuild locally.

```
Step 4/9: Restore packages (NuGet Installer) (5m:07s)
[Step 4/9] Step Restore packages (NuGet Installer) failed
```

Nothing was changed by me concerning TeamCity. Have done already many commits (which resulted into NuGet packages). This error is unclear for me.

EDIT:
Error messages can be seen in the build log below of

> Step 4/9: Restore packages (NuGet Installer) (5m:07s)

For instance:

> [restore] Unable to find version '1.0.0.0' of package
>   'Gnu.Getopt'.
>
> ... and a few other entries with 'Unable to find' ...

So I deleted locally the packages folder within my trunk directory. Subsequently Visual Studio rebuild was invoked. The packages were automatically downloaded and can be used locally. (So to avoid a wrong guess --- they were not deleted at the deployment server)

EDIT 2: Have done another commit. Now this issue does not occur anymore. Worth to mention, I did not any kind of rollback conercerning the old commit, which resulted into the error messages stated above. And the source code of that commit was kept by the way. So the old commit was not the reason for a problem concerning restoring of packages. TeamCity settings are still equal in comparison to last week. For me, that's a solution (because I am hired as software developer and paid for that). (By the way - a TeamCity admin was informed about this issue.) For Stackoverflow, it's not the answer concerning the faulty behaviour that occured last week as described. Thus I did not state my solution as an answer (because this is still open). In another SO thread, I saw a discussion about a mismatch concerning the versions of NuGet.exe and the restore mode but that was not the case for my issue.

Comment: Yes - the same file like two days ago was edited within a project, which was edited a couple of times. But previously no TeamCity issue occured. What changed? To mention it more clearly, the build is failing.

Comment: Yes, I understand that but if the single svn commit has anything to do with it, you really need to start with that commit. Try rolling it back, fully or partially, troubleshoot what was it with that commit that broke the build.